# Is mass a property or a quantity?

Tags: mass, terminology, definition

From definition mass is the amount of matter that an object has. So why we call it a property? What is the difference between a property and a quantity in the dictionary of physics? Wiki says physical quantities are properties that can be measured. But from definition we say is mass is the amount of matter. The meaning of measurement is already exists in the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking at the quantum level, a mass is a property because it is one of several features that we use to define a certain particle. For example an electron has the mass of $0.511\,MeV$ and this sentence has a meaning because **all** electrons have the exact same mass. Specifying the mass, along with other properties such as electric charge, spin and others defines a particle uniquely.

This is unlike, for example, the collective weight of water in a bucket where we can have different amounts of water each with a different mass so knowing the mass of the water in the bucket doesn't really tell you anything important about the water itself.